# protobuf-net v2 r450 inheritance

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

**protobuf-net v2 r450 inheritance**

Hoping someone can help point me in the right direction with protobuf-net. All the sample code I can find seems to indicate what I'm trying should be possible.

Domain (My final domain will be more complex than this but I can't even get this working):

```
[ProtoContract]
public class GeographyData
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public DateTime LastRefreshTime { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2, AsReference = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public GeographyItem Item { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(HotelData))]
public class GeographyItem
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class HotelData : GeographyItem
{
}
```

**Test:**

```
var geographyDataTest = new GeographyData();
geographyDataTest.LastRefreshTime = DateTime.Now;
geographyDataTest.Item = new HotelData
{
    Id = Guid.Empty,
    Name = "Test",
};

var test = ProtoBuf.Serializer.DeepClone(geographyDataTest);
```

Exception:

*Unable to cast object of type 'Domain.Geography.GeographyItem' to type 'Domain.Geography.HotelData'.*

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Domain.Geography.GeographyItem' to type 'Domain.Geography.HotelData'.]
   proto_14(Object , ProtoReader ) +2638
   ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\CompiledSerializer.cs:49
   ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:413
   ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoReader.cs:534
   ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.ReadNetObject(Object value, ProtoReader source, Int32 key, Type type, NetObjectOptions options) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\BclHelpers.cs:428
   proto_2(Object , ProtoReader ) +688
   ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\CompiledSerializer.cs:49
   ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:413
   ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeepClone(Object value) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:1034
   ProtoBuf.Serializer.DeepClone(T instance) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs:46
```

Is anyone able to give me some pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Agreed, it looks like it *should* work. I'm not at a PC, but will look later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [existing known glitch](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=242) with AsReference and inheritance, that I hope to resolve soon.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Marc really appreciated!

Sure enough if I remove the AsReference it works fine, dang I really wanted this :)

Comment: @David I can probably look at this within a few days if you need this

Comment: That would be fantastic, but I know the pain of developing libraries suddenly everyone wants them to work for what they're doing :) so don't kill yourself I'll find another solution I'm sure :)

Comment: @david it is a scenario that should be supported.

Comment: @MarcGravell Did you ever get a chance to fix this?